# Unable to click on Done link. Need help Finding Element or Xpath

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need help getting the xpath or link  from this html

```
<div class="g-btn g-hyperlink " id="s99AB6D3E3FBF404BA01A344322BFA0EE263_2_1"><a onmousemove="window.status='';" onmouseout="window.status='';" name="" href="javascript:;" id="s99AB6D3E3FBF404BA01A344322BFA0EE263_2_1_anchorId" onfocus="DCT.Util.setFocusField('s99AB6D3E3FBF404BA01A344322BFA0EE263_2_1_anchorId');" onclick="DCT.Util.customOnClick(this,&quot;&quot;,{InsertTextAtCursorAction:0,showReminderMessages:0,skipScrollToTop:0});DCT.Util.setFocusField('s99AB6D3E3FBF404BA01A344322BFA0EE263_2_1_anchorId');DCT.Util.processInterviewButtonAnchor('a_s99AB6D3E3FBF404BA01A344322BFA0EE263_2_1_div',&quot;&quot;,&quot;&quot;);" onblur=""><div class="g-btn-l"></div><div class="g-btn-m"><span class="g-btn-text" ext:qtip="" data-tip="" fieldref="Done" xmlns:ext="urn:ext">Cancel</span></div><div class="g-btn-r"></div></a></div>
```

I'm trying to  click in a link but I'm having a hard time getting the xpath .

I have try this

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"onclick,s99AB6D3E3FBF404BA01A344322BFA0EE263_2_1_anchorId")).Click();
    }
```

and this

```
 {Driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Done")).Click();}
```

When I do this  {
            `Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"onclick,s99AB6D3E3FBF404BA01A344322BFA0EE263_2_1_anchorId")).Click();`

I  get this error

```
Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression onclick,s99AB6D3E3FBF404BA01A344322BFA0EE263_2_1_anchorId because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'onclick,s99AB6D3E3FBF404BA01A344322BFA0EE263_2_1_anchorId' is not a valid 
XPath expression.
```

When I try this

```
{

     Driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Done")).Click();}
```

I get this error

`OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a onmousemove="window.status='';" onmouseout="window.status='';" name="" href="javascript:;" id="sF6195287351B43A7BC7610F2A63626FA263_2_1_anchorId" onfocus="DCT.Util.setFocusField('sF6195287351B43A7BC7610F2A63626FA263_2_1_anchorId');" onclick="DCT.Util.customOnClick(this,&quot;&quot;,{InsertTextAtCursorAction:0,showReminderMessages:0,skipScrollToTop:0});DCT.Util.setFocusField('sF6195287351B43A7BC7610F2A63626FA263_2_1_anchorId');DCT.Util.processInterviewButtonAnchor('a_sF6195287351B43A7BC7610F2A63626FA263_2_1_div',&quot;&quot;,&quot;&quot;);" onblur="">...</a> is not clickable at point (310, 605). Other element would receive the click: <div id="s_p900F519A82CE4AE6BA9F48EAF71BBF95144_3_1" class="downLayout x_ statusBar">...</div>`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Added `WebDriverWait`

You can try following `xpath`:

```
//*[@class='g-btn-text' and text()='Cancel']
```

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
IWebElement elmt = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@class='g-btn-text' and text()='Cancel']"));
elmt.Click();
```

Comment: Seem to be a dynamic element and you may have to induce a waiter.

Comment: `Driver.FindElement` change to `Driver`

Comment: I try that but now I'm getting this error OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <span class="g-btn-text" ext:qtip="" data-tip="" fieldref="...">Cancel</span> is not clickable at point (253, 605). Other element would receive the click: <div id="s_p900F519A82CE4AE6BA9F48EAF71BBF95144_3_1" class="downLayout x_ statusBar">...</div>

Answer (score 1):

Use below Xpath:

```
//div[@class='g-btn g-hyperlink ']//span[@class='g-btn-text' and contains(.,'Cancel')]
```

So your code will be like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IWebElement button = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='g-btn g-hyperlink ']//span[@class='g-btn-text' and contains(.,'Cancel')]"));
button.Click();
```

Comment: Seem to be a dynamic element and you may have to induce  a waiter

Comment: I try this but I'm getting this error OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <span class="g-btn-text" ext:qtip="" data-tip="" fieldref="...">Cancel</span> is not clickable at point (253, 605). Other element would receive the click: <div fieldref="Output.NAIC" objectref="p900F519A82CE4AE6BA9F48EAF71BBF95" id="f_p900F519A82CE4AE6BA9F48EAF71BBF95146_3_1" name="f_p900F519A82CE4AE6BA9F48EAF71BBF95146_3_1" class=" x-form-display-field">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)

Comment: Mayi thats a totally different issue, thats means now your xpath issue is resolve and for this issue you can refer DebanjanB answer as : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-elem

Comment: if nothing work use javascript executor .. refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231955/selenium-webdriver-how-to-deal-with-javascript-onclick-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Your locator is not correct, if you really want to use the [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) attribute you should amend it to

- mention [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) tag
- use XPath [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function:

  ```
  Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@onclick,'s99AB6D3E3FBF404BA01A344322BFA0EE263_2_1_anchorId')]")).Click();
  ```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)